# Running netty application in Amazon Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: java, deployment, netty, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a regular netty application server that runs on port 44080 and is built as a .jar file. I would like to use elastic beanstalk to manage the lifecycle of the application. Is there a way I can deploy the jar or something similar using elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

It seems netty is currently not supported by elastic beanstalk. If your application can also run on Tomcat, you could do that - with Tomcat, you just need to enter some basic settings in the webinterface and you´ll get a fully working environment where you can upload jar files to.

If you need netty as a platform, you could try using Amazon OpsWorks. I never worked with it myself, but I know you can create your own "environment configurations" there. You´d basically create a few scripts to setup your server and deploy your application and OpsWorks lets you execute those through the web ui and also provides capabilites for auto-scaling, failover, etc. in OpsWorks environments.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about using Netty. In fact, one of our archetypes for AWS Elastic Beanstalk contains support for Dropwizard (by using Docker as its stack), thus not being dependent on a Java Web Container.

$ mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=elasticbeanstalk-docker-dropwizard

It might need a few tweaks, but the overall idea is to package all your dependencies into a zip file and deploy it. Also, make sure your Dockerfile EXPOSEs port 44080.